# Expandable listview for each item in a listview

Tags: android, expandablelistview

How can I accomplish to make the expandable listview like this:

[image]

[image]

Just ignore that the content of each item is different, how can I make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onItemSingleClick(View v) {
    View dropdown = v.findViewbyId(R.id.dropdown);
    dropdown.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if(mCurrentVisibleDropdown != null)
        mCurrentVisibleDropdown.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mCurrentVisibleDropdown = dropdown;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can setVisibility(VIEW.Visible) of the layer.